# NSLocale.current.description crashing in Xcode 9

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode9

I created a brand new single view application and added one line to the `viewDidLoad` method of the `ViewController.swift` file:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    _ = NSLocale.current.description
}
```

The `NSLocale.current.description` line crashes in Xcode 9 with no stack trace (just a EXC_BAD_ACCESS code=EXC_I386_GPFLT error message). The same project runs fine in Xcode 8.3.3. Anyone have any ideas why this is happening?

[image]

Here is my simulator region settings:

[image]

Comment: You are not using var or let.

Comment: @LeoDabus That is valid code and should not be causing a runtime crash.

Comment: Which build of Xcode 9 are you running? And what is the locale of the system that you are running this on?

Comment: He should be using Locale not NSLocale

Comment: Xcode 9 Beta 2, default iPhone 7 simulator. I attached a screenshot of the Language & Region settings page from the simulator.

Comment: @LeoDabus same crash happens if using `Locale` instead of `NSLocale`.

Comment: try `Locale.current.localizedString(forIdentifier: Locale.current.identifier)`

Comment: Can reproduce in iOS 11 Simulator. It crashes in libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend with EXC_BAD_ACCESS. You should file a bug report.

Comment: Bug report filed.

Comment: It's reproducible in macOS as well.

Comment: @AdamJohns Can you let us know the bug number that you file, either radar or Swift's Jira number?

Comment: Apple bug # 32990161

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug fixed in Xcode 9 Beta 5.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the stack trace, it looks like it's trying to treat `description` as an ObjC property rather than a Swift property. Based on the [source code](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/SDK/Foundation/Locale.swift#L443), this shouldn't be happening. It's likely a bug in the latest Swift compiler that is producing the Swift libraries because it crashes on an iOS 9 device as well.

Be sure to file a [bug with Swift](https://bugs.swift.org) since this seems to be a language bug. I've verified that it is still broken in the latest Swift 4 toolchain. In the meantime, you can get the same behavior of `description` using your own extension by simply duplicating the intended implementation like I've shown here.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // let brokenDescription = NSLocale.current.description
        // let otherBrokenDescription = Locale.current.description

        let objcDescription = (Locale.current as NSLocale).debugDescription //"<__NSCFLocale: 0x1c00dbc10> \'en_US\'}"
        let myDescription = Locale.current.myDescription // "en_US (current)"
    }
}

extension Locale {
    private var _kindDescription : String {
        if self == Locale.autoupdatingCurrent {
            return "autoupdatingCurrent"
        } else if self == Locale.current {
            return "current"
        } else {
            return "fixed"
        }
    }

    public var myDescription: String {
        return "\(identifier) (\(_kindDescription))"
    }

    public var myDebugDescription : String {
        return "\(identifier) (\(_kindDescription))"
    }
}
```